# voip wan on eth0 & internet wan on wlan0

Tags: raspbian, networking, ethernet

I have my rpi as a voip pbx. The rpi is connected to two wans as:

1- voip wan by eth0
2- internet wan by wlan0

On reboot, both interfaces are set as default but the eth0 is prioritized over wlan0. Thus, the pbx success to register the voip line, but no internet access. The good thing is that the voip network ip range is 10.0.0.0/8!

I'm trying to differentiate between those two interfaces (eth0 and wlan0) as:

Use the eth0 for any communication in the range of 10.0.0.0/8 and use the wlan0 for the rest. Make those setups permanent since the rpi get rebooted frequently.

Please advise with best practices to achieve this.